# A closed extension of the Laplace operator with respect to the supremum norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a bounded connected open subset of the $n$-dimensional real euclidean space. Consider the Laplace operator defined on the space of infinitely differentiable functions with compact support in $X$. What is the closure of this operator in the space $C_0(X)$ endowed with the supremum norm? Does its closure generate a strongly continuous semigroup on $C_0(X)$?

Comment: It is good to mention that you have already asked this at MSE, did not get reaction, and reposted here, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438166/core-for-the-laplace-operator-on-a-bounded-domain

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ has the so-called [Wiener-regularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron_method), then it generates an analytic semigroup, see the paper by [Arendt and Bénilan](http://cantor.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/m5/arendt/publications/arendt-pub/short/1999-AreBen-WnrRglHtSmgSpcCntFnc.pdf).

The paper shows this even for unbounded domains, along with the fact that if the regularity assumption is not satisfied, then the Dirichlet-Laplace operator has empty resolvent (hence it is not even a semigroup generator).

For bounded domains and well-posedness (=semigroup generation), see [Gilbarg-Trudinger](http://books.google.hu/books?id=eoiGTf4cmhwC&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false), Section 2.8.

Comment: Thank you. But still I am not sure that the space of infinitely differentiable functions with compact support in X is a core for the Dirichlet Laplacian (If we suppose that the domain X is regular). If yes, this space should be dense in the domain of the laplacian with respect to the graph norm.

Comment: @user36746: It seems to be, but I am not sure at the moment. I am sure that it is the case for sufficiently nice domains, but have to think about the general case.